# Magento 1.9 Colour Swatch handling code -

Tags: magento-1.9, php, color-swatches

Please can someone help me with some PHP code:

Our magento server hosts have identified this section of code as being very resource hungry, is there an alternative route we can take? a module that handles it better? or is it a problem with magento 1.9?

cheers
Russell